# Typescript not compiling to recognise imported functions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am writing some code in Typescript, but am having an issue, with an imported function not being recognised as a function. The paths are fine and VSCode will show me the definitions by linking through to the utilities file.

To show the error here is my setup:

```
import {addElement} from "../../Utilities/scanBLE";
test() {
    addElements("first")
        .then(
        function (val) {
            console.log("second*");
            return addElements("second");
        })
        .then(
        function (val) {
            console.log("third*");
            return addElement("third");
        });
}

function addElements(elementText: string) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve();
        }, 5000);
    })
        .then(function (val) {
            console.log(elementText)
        });
}
```

#### ../../Utilities/scanBLE.ts:

```
export function addElement(elementText: string) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve();
        }, 5000);
    })
        .then(function (val) {
            console.log(elementText)
        });
}
```

This is the log:

> first (./Personal-App/app/Components/Home/home.component.js:95:17)
>
> second* (./Personal-App/app/Components/Home/home.component.js:63:21)
>
> second (./Personal-App/app/Components/Home/home.component.js:95:17)
>
> third* (./Personal-App/app/Components/Home/home.component.js:67:21)
>
> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise):
>
> TypeError: scanBLE_1.addElement is not a function (./Personal-App/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.js:370:13)
>   STACKTRACE: (./Personal-App/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.js:370:13)
>   Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: scanBLE_1.addElement is not a function

the compiled JS looks like this:

```
var scanBLE_1 = require("Utilities/scanBLE");
test() {
    addElements("first")
        .then(function (val) {
        console.log("second*");
        return addElements("second");
    })
        .then(function (val) {
        console.log("third*");
        return scanBLE_1.addElement("third");
    });
};
```

#### Utilities/scanBLE.ts:

```
function addElement(elementText) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve();
        }, 5000);
    })
        .then(function (val) {
        console.log(elementText);
    });
}
exports.addElement = addElement;
//# sourceMappingURL=scanBLE.js.map
```

What's going wrong? Why does the function in the same file work, but not the exact copy of it, which is imported?

Comment: The path in your compiled code: `"Utilities/scanBLE"` doesn't match with the path on your TypeScript code: `"../../Utilities/scanBLE"`. Try to use a relative path, starting with `.` or `..`.

Comment: @Paleo Yes, that was just me editing it for the question titles, the paths seem fine in the actual code.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try

module.exports= addElement;

and for importing with out {}

import addElement from "../../Utilities/scanBLE";

Regards,
Charly